# Missing Faces when Extruding

Tags: modeling, topology

I have a plane that I have inset and then extruded. Is there a way to keep the bottom face when extruding?

[image: inset-extrude]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way extrusion works, if you want the base to be a closed shape, you need to give it thickness (extrude your plane on Z, inset the top, extrude the inner face)